# Storing an RDD as sequence file with partitions?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, rdd, sequencefile

I want to store an java rdd as sequence file with hourly partitioning.Is there any way to achieve this?

For eg:

I have records of type:

```
time,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8
```

I want to have key as a2,a3,a4 and values as all the values in this key and the partitioned column on time.

and in hdfs it will be stored as ::

```
output/time=12345/sequence_file_of_key_and_values

Sample input:
1486203462,1,45,66,77,ansh,72,976,58
1486203461,1,452,66,77,ansh5,456,8754,09865
1486203462,1,45,66,77,ansh9,772,976,5890
1486203461,1,452,66,77,ansh156,742,96,5951
```

Output would be like:

```
output/time=1486203462/a sequence file with key as (1,45,66,77) and corresponding values as ((1486203462,1,45,66,77,ansh,72,976,58),
1486203462,1,45,66,77,ansh9,772,976,5890))

output/time=1486203461/a sequence file with key as (1,452,66,77) and corresponding values as ((1486203461,1,452,66,77,ansh5,456,8754,09865),(1486203461,1,452,66,77,ansh156,742,96,5951))
```

Comment: What is the data type for time column ? Can you sample input and output ?

Comment: hey @mrsrinivas,I have edited input and output.its epoch time with type as string.

Comment: hey @mrsrinivas,you have any idea about it?